# The denominator of a fraction is 4 more than twice the numerator. Determine the fraction.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

The denominator of a fraction is $4$ more than twice the numerator. When both the numerator and denominator are decreased by $6$, the denominator becomes $12$ times the numerator. Determine the fraction.

I tried the following,

Let the numerator be $x$ and the denominator be $y$

Therefore, Fraction$=$ $x$/$4$$+$$2$$x$

Because, both the numerator and denominator are decreased by 6

Therefore, the new fraction becomes $x$$-$6/$($$4$$+$$2$$x$$)$$-$$6$$=$$12$$x$

I do not know how to proceed further.

Comment: I think your last equation isn't right. Shouldn't it be $4+2x-6 = 12\cdot(x-6)$? I think the statement refers to the numerator and denominator of the *modified* fraction, doesn't it?

Comment: "$y$ is $4$ more than twice $x$" translates to $y=4+2x$. So the fraction is $x/y=x/(4+2x)$, which is hardly the same as $x/4+2x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using your notation you have:

$$y=2x+4$$

And the next condition reads:

$$12(x-6)=y-6$$

Because if the denominator is 12 times the numerator that means that your fraction is equal to $\frac{1}{12}$.

So from this system of equations you can get the values of $x$ and $y$. I will give them to you but I'll let you go through the last steps of the process to get them:

$$x=7 \qquad y=18$$

Answer (score -1):

let the numerator be x and let the denominator be y...
in the first part of the question it is said that,x/2x*4(*is plus).in second part of the question it is said that :
x-6/(2x*4)-6.now finally at the last part of the question it is said that: 2x-2=12x[x-6]
2x-2=12x-72
2x-12x= -72+2
-10x=-70
x=7...
in first part of the question we saw that...y=2x+4...now substitute the value of x in that....you get
2.7+4=18...therefore the required fraction is 7/18....hope u understand...[• indicates multiplication]

Comment: useful.clear. good